# Remove space at the bottom of a react-native Text element

Tags: css, react-native, text

I have a Text element and need to position another Text element directly below it.  However, there appears to be space at the bottom of the Text element that keeps me from doing this.  How can I remove the space at the bottom of the Text element with "14.45366" so that the text element with "Current Balance" can then be positioned so it is almost touching "14.45366"?

[image: Example Text Elements]

The purple colored background is to show the amount of space that can be found within the Text element itself.

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 56, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold', textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'purple' }}>14.45366</Text>
<Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_400Regular', textAlign: 'center', color: '#979797' }}>Current Balance</Text>
```

I did try adding lineHeight to the styling but it cuts the text off from the top.
[image: LineHeight]

```
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 56, fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb_600SemiBold', textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'purple', lineHeight: 56 }}>14.45366</Text>
```